# Computation of period Start date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that hold the start date and the end date of a financial period.

```
CHARGE_PERIOD_ID    START_DATE                 END_DATE
13                  2013-03-31 00:00:00.000    2013-04-27 00:00:00.000
14                  2013-04-28 00:00:00.000    2013-05-25 00:00:00.000
15                  2013-05-26 00:00:00.000    2013-06-29 00:00:00.000
16                  2013-06-30 00:00:00.000    2013-07-27 00:00:00.000
17                  2013-07-28 00:00:00.000    2013-08-24 00:00:00.000
18                  2013-08-25 00:00:00.000    2013-09-28 00:00:00.000
19                  2013-09-29 00:00:00.000    2013-10-26 00:00:00.000
20                  2013-10-27 00:00:00.000    2013-11-23 00:00:00.000
21                  2013-11-24 00:00:00.000    2013-12-28 00:00:00.000
22                  2013-12-29 00:00:00.000    2014-01-25 00:00:00.000
23                  2014-01-26 00:00:00.000    2014-02-22 00:00:00.000
24                  2014-02-23 00:00:00.000    2014-03-29 00:00:00.000
```

The user of a report wants the current financial year split into 12 periods and want to give to feed in 2 parameters into the report , a year and a period number which will go into my sql . So something like @year=2014 @period=1 will be recieved . I have to write some sql to go to this table and set a period start date of 31/03/2014 and a period end date of 27/04/2014.

So in pseudo code:

Look up period 1 for 2014 and return period start date of 31/03/2014 and period end date of  27/04/2014.

@PERIOD_START_DATE = select the the first period that starts in March for the given year . all financial period starts in March.

@PERIOD_END_DATE = select the corresponding END_DATE from the table .

The question is how to begin to code this or my design approach? Should I create a function that calcualtes this or should I do a CTE and add a column which will hold the period number in the way they want etc .

Thinking about it more I think I need a mapping table . So the real question is can I do this without a mapping table ?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Looks like your dates are going backward in March of 2014.  Double check that.

Comment: Ok, so it looks like your periods are from the last Sunday of each month to the last Saturday of the next.  Is that correct?  If so, your example needs to be corrected.

Comment: Last suggestion, then I'm going home.  Explain this: "and want to give to feed a variable called period into the sql."

Comment: I am not sure do you want query to read from this table or to add new records to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Year INT 
DECLARE @Period INT

SET @Year= 2013
SET @Period = 1


;WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 
                                CASE WHEN MONTH([START_DATE])<3 THEN YEAR([START_DATE]) -1 ELSE YEAR([START_DATE]) END                              
                                ORDER BY 
                                CASE WHEN MONTH([START_DATE])<3 THEN YEAR([START_DATE]) - 1 ELSE YEAR([START_DATE]) END
                                ,CASE WHEN MONTH([START_DATE])<3 THEN MONTH([START_DATE]) + 12 ELSE MONTH([START_DATE]) END 
                                ) AS RN
FROM Periods
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE RN = @Period 
AND CASE WHEN MONTH([START_DATE])<3 THEN YEAR([START_DATE]) -1 ELSE YEAR([START_DATE]) END = @Year
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/02a68/2)**